# HTML parsing with XPath: flattened hierarchical data

Tags: html, xml, parsing, xpath

My target HTML is a flattened table of  elements with 2 levels of data defined by class attribute:

```
<tr>
    <td class="type">Type 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="name">name1</td>
    <td class="year">1970</td>
    <td class="rank">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="name">name2</td>
    <td class="year">1982</td>
    <td class="rank">3</td>
</tr>
```

Goal is parse out list of name, year, rank elements, which I accomplish with these xpath expressions:

```
//td[@class = 'name']/text()
//td[@class = 'year']/text()
//td[@class = 'rank']/text()
```

Each element is under immediately preceding

```
<tr>
        <td class="type">Type 1</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to have "Type 1" assigned to each element parsed above. It could be separate list of the same length. Of course, my target HTML contains many such elements within the same 2-level hierarchy: type - element (name, year, rank).

Comment: You could use XSLT grouping (or muenchian grouping if you only support XSLT 1.0). But it might be easier using a serial parser (SAX) where you can keep track of the last element of class `type` that was read and attach the data to the nodes that follow.

Comment: Yes, SAX parser is relatively obvious approach, and I spent fair amount of time parsing such HTMLs with SAX before. Usually, it turns out to become bulky hard to maintain code, given that there are multiple HTMLs to parse. I am hoping for some xpath magic...

Comment: So, with XSLT grouping you propose to transform this first with XSLT transform into more uniform XML and then apply XPath... It looks as a valid approach, thanks! Still hoping for XPath only solution for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

First, find the `td` elements of interest. For example, the *name* `td`s with the following pseudo-code:

```
name_tds = doc.evalXPath("//td[@class = 'name']")
```

Then you can find the corresponding *type* `td` using a *name* `td` as context node like this:

```
type_td = name_td.evalXPath("../preceding-sibling::tr[td[@class = 'type']][1]/td")
```

### Solution 2

Simply iterate all the `td`s and remember the last *type* you found. Pseudo-code:

```
foreach (td in doc.evalXPath("//td") {
    class = td.getAttribute("class");
    if (class == "type") {
        type = td.textContent();
    }
    else if (class == "name") {
        name = td.textContent();
        println("type: " + type + ", name: " + name);
    }
    // Same for year and rank.
}
```

Comment: is it in context of some programming language? I don't use neither JavaScript nor Python.

Comment: Yes, this is in the context of some other language. Any language with an XPath engine should work. Or do you have any special requirements?

Comment: No special requirements, but Solution 1 is not clear in the context of XPath library I have (XML package in R). I am actually going with your Solution 2 so far, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following rather clumsy `xpath` concatenates the closest, previous `@type td` to the `name td` matched above.

```
    concat(//td[@class = 'name']/preceding::td[@class='type'][1]/text(), '-',
           //td[@class = 'name']/text())
```

This probably makes more sense when shown in the following xsl

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//td[@class='name']">
        <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(preceding::td[@class='type'][1]/text(), 
                          '-', ./text())" />
        </Name>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Applied to the following xml

```
<xml>
    <tr>
        <td class="type">Type 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">name1</td>
        <td class="year">1970</td>
        <td class="rank">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">name2</td>
        <td class="year">1982</td>
        <td class="rank">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="type">Type 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">name3</td>
        <td class="year">1971</td>
        <td class="rank">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">name4</td>
        <td class="year">1983</td>
        <td class="rank">4</td>
    </tr>
</xml>
```

With the result

```
<Name>Type 1-name1</Name>
<Name>Type 1-name2</Name>
<Name>Type 2-name3</Name>
<Name>Type 2-name4</Name>
```

Comment: thanks, great reply, but I have some difficulties, so far. When applying `//td[@class = 'name']/text()` I get 2066 elements. When applying `//td[@class = 'name']/preceding::td[@class='type'][1]/text()` I get 352 elements. This is fair as it shows how many top level and low level elements I have in total. But applying construct with `concat` function results in only first element concatenated with its top.

Comment: @topchef - yes, that's why the XSLT example - XPath itself is really only suited for a processing a single subject node at a time. I would recommend either using XSLT to parse the whole document as above, or use a language with an xml parser and then e.g. `.SelectNodes(//td[@class = 'name'])`, and iterate through all nodes evaluating `preceding::td[@class='type'][1]/text()`. I'm not saying this can't be done with XPath only - e.g. [a fold could reduce all nodes by applying a function](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.3596&rep=rep1&type=pdf) but this exceeds my skill

Comment: thanks again, I figured that XPath expressions alone is not suited to solve it. I am going with XPath and then simple loop that hopefully saves me from grief while dealing from SAX handlers.